# $(D^5-D)y = 12e^x$ using exponential shift

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is $$(D^5-D)y = 12e^x$$

Here, the general solution of homogenous (D^5-D)y=0 is $y_g = c_1 + c_2 \cos x + c_3 \sin x + c_4 e^x + c_5 e^{-x}$. Now I can apply two methods:

1. Assume particular solution to be $Axe^x$ and solve. This is linearly independant from $y_g$. But finding $D^5$ can be hectic.
2. Use exponential shift:

$$(D^5-D)y = 12e^x\\
y = 12 e^x\frac{1}{(D+1)^5-(D+1)}(1) \\
 = 12 e^x\frac{1}{(D+1)^4-1}(1)\\
 = 12e^x (1+(D+1)^4 + ....)$$

This gives strange answer. What is the proper method for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**. More efficient way is as follows. Let us write $T=D^5-D$. For any $r\in\Bbb C$, we have
$$
T[e^{rx}]=\frac{d^5}{dx^5}e^{rx}-\frac{d}{dx}e^{rx}=(r^5-r)e^{rx}.
$$ Now, differentiate with respect to $r$. Then we get
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial r}T[e^{rx}]=T\left[\frac{\partial }{\partial r}e^{rx}\right]=T[xe^{rx}]=\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left((r^5-r)e^{rx}\right)=(5r^4-1)e^{rx}+(r^5-r)xe^{rx}.
$$ We get by letting $r=1$
$$
T[xe^x]=4e^x.
$$ Hence, $T[3xe^x]=12e^x$ and $3xe^x$ is a particular solution of the equation.

**2**. In fact, correct formula should be
$$
y=12(D^5-D)^{-1}[e^{x}],
$$ not
$$
y=12e^x (D^5-D)^{-1}[1].
$$
Note that $D^5-D=(D-1)(D^4+D^3+D^2+D)$. Since $(D^4+D^3+D^2+D)[e^x]=4e^x$, we have
$$
(D^4+D^3+D^2+D)^{-1}[12e^x]=3e^x.
$$ Finally, since $(D-1)[xe^x]=e^x$, we have
$$
(D-1)^{-1}[3e^x]=(D-1)^{-1}(D^4+D^3+D^2+D)^{-1}[12e^x]=3xe^x.
$$ This also gives a particular solution $3xe^x$.

Comment: sorry i dont understand your method 2

Comment: $$12e^x \stackrel{(D^4+D^3+D^2+D)^{-1}}\Longrightarrow 3e^x\stackrel{(D-1)^{-1}}\Longrightarrow 3xe^x.$$ $$12e^x \stackrel{D^4+D^3+D^2+D}\Longleftarrow 3e^x\stackrel{D-1}\Longleftarrow 3xe^x.$$Can you please be more specific about which part of the argument you don't understand?

Comment: Yes the first line only, from 12ex to 3ex

Comment: @jeea Since $(D^4+D^3+D^2+D)[e^x]=4e^x$, we have $(D^4+D^3+D^2+D)^{-1}[4e^x]=e^x$. By multiplying $3$, we have $(D^4+D^3+D^2+D)^{-1}[12e^x]=3e^x$.

Comment: Oh so we have to observe and predict very carefullly