# Solving $(D^5-D)y = 8\sin x$ using operator methods

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This question is similar to this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3079072/550450) but here it involves $\sin x$ and it creates a problem. I tried writing $\sin x = \Im (e^{ix})$ but that doesnt help:

$$(D^5-D) y = 8\Im (e^{ix})$$

Now $(D^5-D)$ has factor $D=i$ so we need to factor that out and apply it on right side:

$$(D-1)(D+i)(D+1)D y=\frac{1}{D-i}(\Im(e^{ix}))\\
\implies y = \frac{8}{(i-1)(i+1)(2i)(i)}\Im(e^{ix}\int e^{ix} e^{-ix} dx)$$

which gives $y_p = 2x\sin x$. Another method would have been assuming $y_p = x(A\cos x + B\sin x)$ but that too would have been lengthy

Is the method in this answer correct, because it is using complex numbers loosely. Is this operator method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same method suggested in [**1**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3079072/d5-dy-12ex-using-exponential-shift). Let us find a solution $y$ of the equation
$$
(D^5-D)[y]=8e^{ix}
$$ first. Write $T=D^5-D$. For any $r\in\Bbb C$, it holds that
$$
T[e^{rx}]=D^5[e^{rx}]-D[e^{rx}]=(r^5-r)e^{rx}.
$$ Plugging $r=i$ into the equation does not give the solution because $i^5-i=0$. Now, by differentiating both sides with respect to $r$, we get
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial r}T[e^{rx}]=T[\frac{\partial}{\partial r}e^{rx}]=T[xe^{rx}]=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left((r^5-r)e^{rx}\right)=(5r^4-1)e^{rx}+(r^5-r)xe^{rx}.
$$
Plugging $r=i$ into the expression, we get
$$
T[xe^{ix}]=(5i^4-1)e^{ix}+(i^5-i)xe^{ix}=4e^{ix}.
$$ This shows $T[2xe^{ix}]=8e^{ix}$. By separating real and imaginary parts, we get
$$
T[2x\cos x]=8\cos x,\quad T[2x\sin x]=8\sin x.
$$ This allows us a particular solution $y(x) =2x\sin x$ satisfying $T[y]=8\sin x$.

Comment: THanks a lot again! is the method I put in the question also fine

Comment: @jeea It came close to being right ... Note that to invert $(D-i)$, i.e. to get $(D-i)^{-1}[f]$, we should calculate the convolution$$\int_0^x e^{i(x-t)}f(t)dt .$$ In this case, $$\int_0^x e^{i(x-t)}e^{it}dt =\int_0^x e^{ix}dt = xe^{ix}.$$